# postgresql / postgres grant permissions to everything in the current schema

Tags: postgresql

I know I can run this:

```sql
grant select on all tables in schema whatever to "my_dev_group";
```

but the way I've built our CI system - we use lots of different schemas, so the schema is only known at the time of running the tests - *not* when the script is written.   Ie we run the same script *against* lots of different test schemas and we set the schema name at the start...

so I am trying to achieve the equivalent of the above grant statement - but to operate on the *current* schema - without any success.

ie all of these were spectacularly unsuccessful

```sql
grant select on all tables in schema current to "my_dev_group";
grant select on all tables in schema current_schema() to "my_dev_group";
grant select on all tables to "my_dev_group";
```

is it possible to do without going into the world of executing dynamic sql, which I'd prefer not to

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't have a notion of a “current schema”.  Consequently, there is no syntax to change the permissions of all tables in the current schema.

You could loop through all schemas in the `search_path` or all schemas in the database and run a `GRANT` statement for each one. Make sure to skip system schemas like `information_schema` and `pg_catalog`.

Alternatively, you could use the `current_schema()` function to retrieve the first existing schema on your `search_path` and change permissions for that schema.

Comment: this code works - I was just hoping for a better way: `do '
    declare sql text = concat(''grant select on all tables in schema '' , current_schema() , '' to "my_dev_group";'' );
   begin
   execute sql;
end;
';`

Comment: Yes, there is the `current_schema()` function. I'll update my answer.

Comment: the point of the question though - is _how_ do I use the current_schema function?   I am currently using it in my dynamic sql above - and it works - is there any way of doing the same thing _without_ dynamic sql?

Comment: No, you need dynamic SQL for that.